# Expand UILabel and UICollectionView cell based on UILabel size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uilabel

I have a UICollectionView setup in the following way:

[image]

Where it says "pretty" is a UILabel. Currently, I truncate the text if it goes beyond the label's size.

Is there a way to expand the UILabel and CollectionViewCell vertically to fit all of the text?

Thank you!

***EDIT:***

What I've implemented so far:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CollectionViewCellimage *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"birthdayCollView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PhotoClass *photoClass = [arrBirthdayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lblDescription.text = photoClass.description;
    // same implementation for other fields
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post here what you've implemented so far in CollectionViewCell?

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic done

Comment: If you've used autolayout then post a screenshot.

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic just did

Comment: if your constrains are proper then, Have you tried with flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
By seeing your layout, Hope you've set fix height of your first label, then image and bottom buttons. Only 2nd label's height is not fixed and numberOfLiinesTo = 0

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic I have not done that. Could you please put that in a more elaborate answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set your cell's constraints like this.

- 1st Label : Top, Left, Right, Bottom to image. (height also if this is only single line)
- Image: (CenterX, Width) or (Left, Right) and height, bottom to 2nd Label.
- 2nd Label:
  Align left, right to image, numberOfLines = 0, bottom constraint to
  BottomView.
- BottomView: Bottom constraint to superView, height, left,
  right.

Then in your view controller set **estimatedItemSize** for collectionView.

```
//Set CollectionView Layout

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];
self.flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);



-(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)flowLayout{


if(!_flowLayout) {

    _flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [_flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topSpacing, leftMargin, bottomSpacing, rightMargin)];
    [_flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:cellSpacing];
    [_flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:lineSpacing];
    [_flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
}

  return _flowLayout;
}
```